# HTML - Calling JS Function from External File

Tags: javascript, html

I've started playing around with JS but I'm having some trouble calling a function from an external file.

I've tried most solutions in other questions posted here but still cannot get the function to execute.

I have the following JS File (myjs.js):

```
console.log("Loaded JS");

//Startup function
function setup(){
    console.log("Testing");
}

setup();
```

And here's the HTML which uses it:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js"/>
  </head>

  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript"> setup(); </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

I've tried loading the script in the body and then calling the `setup()` function, and expect to see the following in the console:

```
Loaded JS //From loading JS
Testing   //From loading JS
Testing   //Invoking setup
```

Instead I only see:

```
Loaded JS
Testing
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The `setup();` in the body and the `setup();` that you probably have in your `myjs.js` file seem to be running at different times. 
 Check here to consolidate your myjs.js file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the

Comment: @ntgCleaner — They aren't running at different times. One isn't running at all.

Comment: @Quentin, you're right.  I really just wanted to give him the link to a way to fix it.

Comment: @ntgCleaner — The link doesn't say anything that is remotely relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Quentin, The answer to that question details multiple ways to fire events when a page loads.

Comment: @ntgCleaner — None of which deals with the problem … which is that the end tag for the script element is missing.

Comment: @Quentin, Let's hope that's his only problem.  I'll cheer for your answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

The end tag for a script element (`</script>`) is mandatory.

Since you omitted it from your first script element, everything following it (including the start tag for your second script tag) up until `</script>` is inside that script.

Since the script has a `src`, the body is ignored.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have sorted it.